# itemBuilder error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Widget' doesn't allow null

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, gradle

I'm trying to add the Firestore database to my Flutter progect, but I can't figure out how to use a ListView.builder to show every element on an array in my database since it gives me this error: `A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Widget' doesn't allow null` on line 56.
Could you help me? Here's the code: https://hastebin.com/ipayedezoc.js

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the firebase returns for you?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Does it return any data? You return a null value in your builder method, instead of a widget.

Comment: My firebase should return some strings

Comment: And does it? DId you try to print the string to check if it returns what it should?

Comment: The problem is that the code does not even enter in the for loop, so I can't know it
However, it should return it since before, with a similar formula, it returned the right strings

Comment: If it does not enter the for loop, I don't think it has the `name` field. Therefor it is 0, does not enter the for cycle and it returns null. I suggest you to make sure what the firebase returns.

Comment: if i may ask why are looping inside single item ?  on ListView.builder

Comment: The Builder function has a parameter ```i``` which you hide by using i as the index variable in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help?

```
 itemBuilder: (ctxt, i) {

                        ///for single item returns
                        // for(int i = 0; i < name['name'].length; i++){
                        //   ///may be you just to print out
                        // }
                        //  return ListTile(title: Text(name['name'][i])); 

                     ///for item list 
                     List<Widget> widgtes = [];
                        for(int i = 0; i < name['name'].length; i++){
                          ///may be you just to print out
                          widgtes.add(ListTile(title: Text(name['name'][i])));
                        }
                         return Column(
                           children: widgtes,
                         );
```